# Cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException;

public class JDBCExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        //connect to the db
        try{
            String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Lab4; user=sa; password=password;";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server but I don't know why I got wrong.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to  the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Did I get wrong on String conURL or about the port? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: In conURL, try eliminating the spaces -- `String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Lab4;user=sa;password=password;";`

Comment: Also remove the trailing `;`

Comment: Do you actually have an *unnamed* SQL Server Database Instance running on your local computer?

Comment: @Andreas I'm trying to run on localhost. I'm not sure about my conURL so I think that is the problem

Comment: You didn't answer my question, so I'll repeat it: Do you actually have an *unnamed* SQL Server Database Instance **installed** and **running** on your *local* computer?

Comment: Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and go to Server Protocols > TCP/IP to see which port, if any, your SQL Server is listening on. You'll need that port number in your connection string, e.g.: `"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:4567;"` if it's listening on port 4567. If you're running an Express edition of SQL Server it may not even have a TCP/IP port listening.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I did. I had SQL Server Management Studio. I created a localhost with username:sa and password: password

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is a GUI tool for connecting to databases, it is not a database in itself. Did you install the **Database Engine**, not just the tool?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-downloads 
Did you mean the one on that page? If yes, I did installed

Comment: Also, I did installed the Database Engine